# Bootstrap modal callbacks in IE 9+

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my function :

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
    $('#myModal').one('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        alert('abcd') // if I put alert it works    
        set_something();
    });

    //init modal
    $('#myModal').modal(); 
});

function set_something(){
    somevariable = 1

}
```

In every browsers it works ok, but in IE 9+ does not. As I write upper, it only works in IE when I put alert on it - if not, function set_something() isn't executed on shown.bs.modal

Have somebody get this to work in IE?

ANSWER :

I do not get simple fix, but I made something like ( for remote loaded content to modal). I do not put it on callback "shown", because IE9 do not see it - I put it when button for open modal is clicked :

```
var fix_ie9 = setInterval(function(){
    if ( $('.modal-check').length ) { // my empty div in remote content only for check
        set_something()
            clearInterval(fix_ie9);
    }
}, 1000);
```

and I think that this hack should work.

Comment: I am absolutely sure it works without alert, put a jsfiddle please and i will show you that the problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: I won't try ... I almost make colorbox working in that same way without problems.

Comment: What's actually in `set_something`? If the `alert` call is allowing that to work as intended, it's likely that you're making a faulty assumption about elements that exist on the page or code that has run before `set_something` "works".

Comment: in set_something is somevariable += 1 ... and it does not work only on IE9 .. right now I install IE10, on IE11 works ok. It maybe has something do to with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801711/show-event-doesnt-fire-in-ie9-using-twitter-bootstrap-modal-in-rails ... I also read that IE9 need to have addEventListener ...

Comment: If you won't try, don't wait for a response. You can't wait for others to help you if you are not willing to type the question first.

Comment: I wrote question, You can't help, do not know why IE behaves in this way. What more You want? I should wasting time for you to romp a little? I got some fix and wrote it earlier than You left this comment.